# How to sum multiple values in a entry in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say I have the following df:

```
teamid      scores
1            10
2            11
```

Where the first number (i.e. **1**0) is the first score and the second number (i.e. 1**0**) is the second score. How would I sum the scores together in the df?

result df:

```
teamid      Combinedscore
1             1
2             2
```

Comment: Did you meant `df$Combinedscore <- rowSums(read.fwf(textConnection(as.character(df$scores)), width = c(1, 1)))`

Comment: Yep that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyr` and `dplyr` solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)   
df %>%
  extract(scores, 
          into = c("1","2"), 
          regex = "(.)(.)",
          convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(combinedScore = rowSums(across(c("1","2")))) %>%
  select(-c(2,3))
  teamid combinedScore
1      1             1
2      2             2
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  teamid = c(1:2),
  scores = c(10, 11)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `read.fwf` from `base R` to split the scores column into multiple columns, and get the `rowSums` of each digit to create the 'Combinedscore'

```
df$Combinedscore <- rowSums(read.fwf(textConnection(as.character(df$scores)), 
       widths = rep(1, max(nchar(df$scores)))), na.rm = TRUE)
```

-output

```
> df
  teamid scores Combinedscore
1      1     10             1
2      2     11             2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(teamid = 1:2, scores = 10:11), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **base R** using `strsplit` with `sapply`

```
df$Combinedscore <- 
   colSums( sapply( strsplit( as.character(df$scores),"" ), as.numeric ) )

  teamid scores Combinedscore
1      1     10             1
2      2     11             2
```